# Rotate clock hand using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div class="clock">
<div class="space">
<div class="hourhand"></div>
<div class="minutehand"></div>
<div class="sechand" id="secc"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
function date(){
  var d = new Date();
  const sec= d.getSeconds();
  var x = document.getElementById('secc');
  x.style.transform="rotate(sec)";
  console.log(sec);
}
setInterval(date, 1000);
```

I am making this simple clock using vanilla js.(I have not shown the CSS code).
The line in script tag - `x.style.transform` does not take `sec` as its input?
Then how should I pass the `sec` value to this to make it rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when you use css [transofrm-rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#rotate()), you need to specify a [unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/angle)(rad/deg/turns).

Second thing is, your javascript object doesn't magicly turn themselfs into valid css values, you need to build the css values like this:

```
x.style.transform="rotate(" + (6 * sec) + "deg)";
```

Notice the `6*sec` because we want to have 360 degrees each turn(from 60 in each second).

Comment: > Why have we multiplied by 6?

Comment: Because to make a full turn we need 360 degrees from our seconds value, so 360/60=6.
The same can be done with the `rad` / `turn` units.

Answer (score 1):

[Rotate](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#funcdef-rotatez) syntax:

```
transform: rotateZ(90deg)
```

This would cause a rotation by 90 degrees in the Z-plane, however in your case you have a variable which you need to pass in. So you need to convert your seconds to degrees.

1. Total degrees spanned by seconds hand in a minute = 360 degrees
2. Seconds in one Minute = 60s
3. Degrees spanned in 1 second = (360degrees/60 seconds) = 6 degrees

   ```
   transform: rotateZ(`${sec * 6}deg`)
   ```

For your code:

```
x.style.transform=`rotateZ(${sec * 6}deg)`;
```

Comment: What is this syntax, I dont understand this? But i have seen this many a times.

Comment: @sugandhgoyal This is just an ES6 way of converting an expression/variable to its `string` equivalent. Here, it multiplies `sec` with `6` and `${}` converts that to a string which gets concatenated by deg. `\`\`` can also take multi-line strings.

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS `transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is used to control a lot of different transformations, the one you're looking for is `rotate`.

Rotations are specified in either `deg` (degrees, 0-360), `rad` (radians, 0-2*π) or `turn` (0-1)

I'd go for the `turn` in this case, as the calculation of the rotation is very straight forward: `now / max` (e.g. three o'clock in the afternoon: `15 / 24`)

Simple example (note: I haven't bothered too much with aligning the handles)

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date(),
      positions = [
        date.getHours() / 24,
        date.getMinutes() / 60,
        date.getSeconds() / 60
      ],
      clock = document.querySelector('.clock');

  positions.forEach(function(rotation, index) {
    clock.children[index].style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'turn)';
  });

}, 1000);
```

```css
.clock {
  position:  relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.clock > * {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height:  50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.hourhand {
  height: 30%;
}

.sechand {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="hourhand"></div>
  <div class="minutehand"></div>
  <div class="sechand"></div>
</div>
```

If you'd like a more of Rolex effect (which doesn't tick per second), you can set the interval very short (e.g. 20ms) and calculate the secondhand rotate based on `getTime` rather than `getSeconds` (`getTime` provides the number of milliseconds since the "Unix Epoch" (`1970-01-01 00:00:00.000`), e.g.:

```
date.getTime() / 60000
```